# Query to get all nested associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

I'm kind of confused here with my queries.

So, I have a `Task` model and a `User` model.

Tasks have an `assignee_id` column, pointing to the `user` who the task has been assigned to.

On the other hand, the `User` model has the following:

```
has_many :tasks, foreign_key: :assignee_id
has_many :supervised_users, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :supervisor_id
```

So, I can call:

```
user.supervised_users => returns all users supervised by this user
user.tasks => returns all tasks assigned to the user
```

Now, what I want to do is to get all tasks(meeting some criteriums) assigned to all users supervised by a given user

**Example:**

- user A is supervising users B, C & D
- user B has tasks x(completed) & y(not completed)
- user C has tasks g(completed) & j(not completed)
- user D has tasks h(completed), n(not completed) & t(completed)

I need a query to return completed tasks by supervised users (i.e tasks x, g, h & t).

How can I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I never knew that I could just concatenate the two like so: `A.supervised_users.joins(:tasks).where(<_conditions_>)`. But I did that and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is how I would do it - in two stages, first use a through relationship to get all supervised_tasks (complete and incomplete)

In the user class add:

```
has_many :supervised_tasks, through: :supervised_users, class_name: 'Task'
```

You'll probably need to have a source field in there as well, so, something like ',source: :tasks' added to the end of that.

Test by trying out 'user.supervised_tasks'

then I would create a scope in the tasks class, to identify completed tasks, so something like (assuming it's a boolean, modify if not):

```
scope :completed, -> { where(completed: true) }
```

Then you can call user.supervised_tasks.completed

You can then even add that to your user model as a scoped has_many through:

has_many :completed_supervised_tasks, -> { completed }, through: :supervised_users, class_name: 'Task'

Think that should do it..